# перезагрузка страницы с отправкой формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Нужно перезагружать страницу раз в секунду и оправлять form методом post. в форме нужно отправлять переменную, которую до этого получили.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Авторизация</title>
<meta content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form" action="/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="${sessionId}"/>
</form>
<p>Ваш sessionId: ${sessionId}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас форма не отправляется.